# Make classes appear on TOC in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I'm starting to document a few python classes using ext.autodoc. I have several *.rst files with content such as

```
========
mymodule
========

.. automodule:: mymodule
   .. autoclass:: myclassA
       :members:
   .. autoclass:: myclassB
       :members:
```

plus an index.rst:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   mymodule
```

'mymodule' shown in the table of contents, but I'd also like to see the classes in the TOC too:

- mymodule

  - myclassA
  - myclassB

How can I make sphinx create something like a section for each class? Or is there a good reason not to do so?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx cannot create sections. You'll have to add them yourself in the .rst file. Something like this:

```
myclassA
--------

.. autoclass:: myclassA
   :members:

myclassB
--------

.. autoclass:: myclassB
   :members:
```

For some alternative suggestions that might be interesting, see these questions (and the answers):

- [Sphinx customizing autoclass output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14903111/407651)
- [Sorting display by class using sphinx with 'autodoc'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14606348/407651)