# Can the Sphinx "automodule" be told to automatically insert section breaks between members?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, autodoc

This question is inspired by the [Mayavi documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_pipeline_other_functions.html), which has nice section breaks with the name of the function being described between each module member.

My `.rst` right now just looks like:

```
SQLAlchemy Tables
**********************************

.. automodule:: ExperimentOrganizer.table_def
    :members:
```

(With all of the documentation formatted text in the module itself.)

Is there a simple way to indicate that I'd like to have section headers inserted between each member in `:members:`? If not, how did the Mayavi folks do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can the Sphinx "automodule" be told to automatically insert section breaks between members?*

No. There is no magic option to `automodule` or something like that. If you want section headers then you'll have to add them yourself (perhaps by using a script) to the reST source. See also the answer to this similar question: [Sphinx customizing autoclass output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573193/407651).

The [Mayavi documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_pipeline_other_functions.html) that you refer to is not created with [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/autodoc.html). The functions are documented using the [`function`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:function) directive (not `autofunction`). Click on "Show Source" to see the reST markup.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lengthy and cumbersome workaround: You first document the class without any members, then you insert the section header yourself, and then you document the members *one by one*.

Example using the class from https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html, which also states the directives:

```
.. currentmodule:: module.name

Documentation
-------------

.. autoclass:: Noodle

Attributes
----------

.. autoattribute:: Noodle.eat
.. autoattribute:: Noodle.slurp
.. autoamethod:: Noodle.boil
```