# Sphinx: How to insert something between classes using automodule?

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to auto-document Django based models with https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2533/.

The problem I have is that classes as listed one by one. Is there any way to add a subsection before each class?

For example:

```
<obj._meta.db_table>
---------------------

class models.Actor(*args, **kwargs)
   parameters:...


<obj._meta.db_table>
---------------------

class models.Dog(*args, **kwargs)
   parameters:...
```

because I receiving something like that:

```
class models.Actor(*args, **kwargs)
   parameters:...

class models.Dog(*args, **kwargs)
   parameters:...
```

Comment: If your models don't change very often, you could just use autoclass instead.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14903111/407651