# Keeping the API updated in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The scheme is the following. There exists a package called `foo` (an API under heavy development, in first alpha phases) whose `rst` files are auto generated with `sphinx-apidoc`.

For the sake of having a better documentation for `foo` after those files are generated, there is some editing. In, say, `foo.bar.rst` there are some paragraphs added to the contents generated with `sphinx-apidoc`

How can I not loose all that information when a new call of `sphinx-apidoc` is made? And of course I want potential changes in the API to be reflected, with that manual information added being preserved.

Comment: In one of my projects (which uses git), I keep a separate orphan-branch to keep track of all sphinx related changes. Then whenever we need to generate the documentation in html, I branch off from master, and merge the sphinx branch in. That ways, all changes related to sphinx are versioned, and any over-writes due to *work-in-progress* is avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sphinx-apidoc` only needs to be re-run when the module structure of your project changes.  If adding, removing, and renaming modules is an uncommon occurrence for you, it may be easiest to just place the rst files under version control and update them by hand.  Adding or removing a module only requires changing a few lines of rst, so you don't even need to use `sphinx-apidoc` once you've run it once.