# Can you autodoc only submodules using sphinx-apidoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I use sphinx-click extension for my click application, and i want to use sphinx-apidoc to generate .rst files for *only* submodules.

I've been working with pythons Sphinx documentation library for about a year now, and I have a usecase... I cannot quite figure out.. maybe I'm just blind right now.

Anyways, I have a cli tool structured something like

```
my_tool/
+-- __init__.py
+-- cli_entry.py
+-- utils
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- foo.py
|   +-- bar.py
```

Where cli_entry is a click application, and it imports `my_tool.utils.foo` and `my_tools.utils.bar`
Since this is using the Click library. I've decided to use the `sphinx_click` extension to document any command that is in `cli_entry.py` (which documents all the commands great).

But heres the issue, I want to use `sphinx-apidoc` to generate the .rst files for everything that is in the `./my_tool/utils/` modules.
When I use the command as `sphinx-apidoc -o ../docs/utils my_tool/utils` the output files that I get include

```
docs/
+-- utils
|   +-- module.rst
|   +-- utils.rst
```

Which looks great at first, but upon opening `utils.rst` the file looks something like

```
utils package
=============

Submodules
----------

utils.foo module
----------------------

.. automodule:: utils.foo
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

utils.bar module
----------------------

.. automodule:: utils.bar
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Then when I build the documentation using `make html` (from sphinx generated makefile) I get an error saying `Failed to import 'utils.foo': no module named utils.foo` thats because the import should exist as `my_tool.utils.foo`

How can I use `sphinx-apidoc` to generate only submodules **and** include the correct import paths?? Maybe its something I'm missing in the `conf.py`.. maybe it's an option I'm missing from sphinx-apidoc?

EDIT: I should mention that I could use the `exclude_pattern` argument... but I would prefer to not have to specify each cli file in my root. ex. In the case that I have `cli_entry.py`, `cli_commandgroup1.py`... `cli_commandgroupN.py`. I want this solution to be dynamic enough to just support only submodules.

EDIT: I tried using `sphinx-apidoc -o ../docs/utils my_tool/` and this creates the following output

```
docs/
+-- utils
|   +-- module.rst
|   +-- my_tool.cli_entry.rst
|   +-- my_tool.utils.rst
```

Now in the `my_tool.utils.rst` file, the imports are correct, and the docs can be generated.

```
my_tool.utils.foo module
----------------------

.. automodule:: my_tool.utils.foo
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

The issue with specifying `my_tool/` is that `my_tool.cli_entry.rst` gets created, when this .rst file would already be created using the click-sphinx extension.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use sphinx-apidoc. You can write the needed RST markup yourself to ensure that only specific modules get documented. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481785/407651.

Comment: What does utils.rst look like if you run `sphinx-apidoc -o ../docs/utils my_tool/`?

Comment: @mzjn, I would prefer to not need to write and maintain the RST files, and would like to rely the generation of RST files from sphinx-apidoc. If i use `sphinx-apidoc -o ../docs/utils my_tool/` Everything gets documented correctly. I'll update my post to share why this will not work.

Comment: OK. I don't think there is a way to use sphinx-apidoc for your particular use case that does not require some post-processing (removing and/or editing generated RST files).

Comment: @mzjn thats what I was afraid of. Thanks for sharing